# Draw an arc/circle sector in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, draw, geometry, sector

I know that it is possible to draw a circle in QML using the following code:

```
Rectangle {
     width: 150
     height: 150
     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
     anchors.top: parent.top
     color: "#095e7b"
     border.color: "#0a2f4a"
     border.width: 2
     radius: width*0.5
}
```

My question is: what if I need to draw a sector of a circle. (Pizza Slices) and make each of these slices clickable? Can I do this using QML only?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, using Canvas (and [Context2D](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#arc-method)):

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.reset();

            var centreX = width / 2;
            var centreY = height / 2;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.moveTo(centreX, centreY);
            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width / 4, 0, Math.PI * 0.5, false);
            ctx.lineTo(centreX, centreY);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.moveTo(centreX, centreY);
            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width / 4, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 2, false);
            ctx.lineTo(centreX, centreY);
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }
}
```

I actually took the code for this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230363/how-to-draw-a-circle-sector-on-an-html5-canvas) answer, as Qt's Canvas implements the HTML5 Canvas API. This makes it really easy to find examples on the web; just search for "draw pie slice blah html5 canvas", for example.

For the mouse detection, you'll have to brush off your maths skills...

... or just steal the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755292/get-mouse-position-relative-to-pie-chart-equation). :)

Note that Canvas only repaints when it's resized, or when [requestPaint()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#requestPaint-method) is called, so if you want to change the colour of a slice depending on the mouse position, you'll need to call that function to see the colour change.

Answer (score 15):

Draw it using qml, you don't need the canvas. As a guideline I usually go through Qt's examples before deciding on an implementation. The code below can be found in "Shapes" example.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15

Shape {
    width: 120
    height: 130
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.right: parent.right
    // multisample, decide based on your scene settings
    layer.enabled: true
    layer.samples: 4

    ShapePath {
        fillColor: "black"
        strokeColor: "darkBlue"
        strokeWidth: 20
        capStyle: ShapePath.FlatCap

        PathAngleArc {
            centerX: 65; centerY: 95
            radiusX: 45; radiusY: 45
            startAngle: -180
            sweepAngle: 180
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using shape against canvas? Wish there was a performance  comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Use charts http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qtcharts-qmlmodule.html

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.0

ChartView {
width: 400 
height: 300
theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
antialiasing: true

PieSeries {
    id: pieSeries
    PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
    PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
}
}
```

Comment: Licensing alert! Those of us writing commercial code need to be aware: unlike most of Qt, QtCharts is not licensed under LGPL. If your product is closed source, you would need a commercial Qt license to use QtCharts.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was about drawing "pizza slices" *and making each of them clickable*, an important detail is mapping clicks to the right segment (aka the right "pizza slice").

None of the prior answers seem to contain any `onClicked` handling, so I offer yet another possibility. (All the prior answers are also valid, they just don't make it immediately clear where to intercept clicks.)

I had a similar case wherein I needed to slice a rectangle on a 45 degree diagonal, and detect whether clicks fall above or below the diagonal line.

Thankfully, it turns out that QML allows you to:

- create a grid
- apply a `transform: Rotation` to that grid
- ... and then automatically your clicks "just work"

  - (meaning: clicking on a 45-degree rotated rectangle maps as you would wish)

The demo code renders a rotated grid like the following, and outputs (via `console.log`) the color that you click on:

[image: rotated grid of QML rectangles]

The following has been tested on Ubuntu using Qt 5.14

```
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

Item {
  height: 1000
  width: 2000

  GridLayout {
    id: grid
    columnSpacing: 0 // the default is non-zero!
    rowSpacing: 0
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    rows: 2
    columns: 2

    Rectangle {
      height: 200
      width: 200
      color: 'red'
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
          console.log('red')
        }
      }
    }
    Rectangle {
      height: 200
      width: 200
      color: 'yellow'
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
          console.log('yellow')
        }
      }
    }
    Rectangle {
      height: 200
      width: 200
      color: 'green'
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
          console.log('green')
        }
      }
    }
    Rectangle {
      height: 200
      width: 200
      color: 'blue'
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
          console.log('blue')
        }
      }
    }
    transform: Rotation {
      origin.x: grid.width * 0.5
      origin.y: grid.height * 0.5
      axis {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        z: 1
      }
      angle: 45
    }
  }
}
```