# How do I create a triangle in QML that changes size based on degrees?

Tags: qt, object, qml

I'm pretty new to QML. I'm trying to create a triangle (slice of a pie) that changes size based on the number of degrees that I pass in. For instance, if I pass in 360 it should be a full circle and if I pass in 90 degrees then it should be a quarter of a circle. What object from QML can I use to achieve this?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw an arc/circle sector in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044801/draw-an-arc-circle-sector-in-qml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shape](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html) to draw some custom path, for example:

```js
Shape {
    id: shape
    width: 300
    height: 200
    antialiasing: true
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    ShapePath {
        id: path
        strokeWidth: 1
        strokeColor: "#999"
        fillColor: "#abebc6"
        startX: 0; startY: shape.height / 2
        PathLine { x: shape.width * 0.9; y: 0 }
        PathArc {
            x: shape.width * 0.9
            y: shape.height
            radiusX: shape.height;
            radiusY: shape.height
            useLargeArc: false
        }
        PathLine { x: 0; y: shape.height / 2 }
    }
}
```

The same can be done using [Canvas](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html)

Comment: Where are you using the number of degrees? The size needs to adjust based on the number of degrees.

Comment: I think it won't be difficult for to convert the angle into coordinates. I just gave an example of an implementation.